# How can you get the specific spaces you want to remove in notepad ++

Tags: notepad++, notepad

Example:

```
I want to remove the
space
I want to remove the
space
I want to remove the 
space
```

How can I remove the word SPACE so that the three sentences will be a complete thought. 
Is there a command to do it in just one click?

Or

I have to do it manually?

Here's another example:

```
ColorFuse Powercore, Narrow Beam
Angle
ColorFuse Powercore, Medium Beam
Angle
Special ColorFuse Powercore, 2700K,
Narrow Beam Angle
```

I hope there's someone here knows the answer.

Comment: Do you want to remove the word 'space' or the space between 'the' and 'space', as your second example suggests? Please show how your output should look after replacement.

Answer (score 0):

In NotePad++:

1. Open the Replace dialog from the Search->Replace... menu (or Ctrl+H)
2. Set the 'Search Mode' to 'Extended'
3. Set 'Find what' to `\r\nspace\r\n`
4. Set 'Replace with' to a single space character (or your desired separator)
5. Click 'Replace All' button.

Answer (score 0):

i start to use [SublimeText](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) and my life is changed))
You can use in it multiple selection it very easy and very usefull for day to day tasks.

What about your case, [snowdude](https://superuser.com/a/461870/107875) give you very easy way how to do it, also u can replace it with regexp which you can find in search.